# Vue.js: Backend realization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, design-patterns, backend

So, I have been learning Vue.js as my first js framework for some time and after I made some simple SPA:s without much interactions with a server I started to wonder: What should a backend be like with Vue? For education purposes I gave it a try and came up with some pattern on my own and now I can't imagine anything else, maybe I got some wrong idea.

What I came up with: I made a simple API with PHP which was receiving requests from the frontend (Vue component methods reacting on UI events) and requesting data from the model or updating data through it.

Comment: Another approach... [Server-Side Rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different Backend Solutions and you should take what fits your websites purpose and also personal preference the best.

**If Backend includes Hosting** in your case then you basicly have the 2 big options:

a) A Server where you run it ex. via an Reverse Proxy (example: Digital Ocean)

b) A cloud computing Platform (example: AWS, Heroku, App Engine)

But you only need to host it that way if you actually run the app and retrieve dynamic updates on the page, new routes get added when you for example publish a new Post.

If that is not the case then a static hosting provider would be enough, there are 1000´s of them and they are pretty uncomplicated.

**If you mean which Database to use**, then it also comes down to preference, do you want a SQL Databse or a NoSQL Database like MongoDB? As a personal recommendation I would suggest you to use Firebase as your backend for your experimental app, the free plan is far than enough for testing purposes, you also have a smooth and easy to integrate Authentication System avaliable and you can also take quick advantage of things like Push Messages, Cloud Storage Buckets and more.

Note that Im not related to FB by any means and this is just a personal recommendation, but I feel like your Question is pretty opinion based so maybe be more specific about your goals or just comment down below if you got any more questions.

Comment: Thank you, but i actually asked not quite this or i may have not quite gotten you. There is no really hosting yet, just apache server running locally and MySQL base existing also locally (for now). I was asking more about realization in MVC (MVVM) which i personally saw only making an API as the only option